# Composite Variables and Levels of Measurement

Tags: regression, least-squares, ordinal-data, composite

I have six worry items (worrying about economy, health, etc. and 1-Not worried, 2-Somewhat worried, 3-Very worried) and I want to create a composite variable to see if I can use all worries in a single variable (worry scale) and make this the dependent variable for my study.

Creating composite worry variable (worry scale) I followed two different paths in SPSS;

1-Created a new variable using the mean of the total scores for each case (did not lose any cases),

2-Simply add the scores for each case and divided them 6 (number of worry items) and this cases lost some cases,

Now I have two questions:

1-Which option is better (I assume option 1 seems better since it keeps the cases otherwise goes missing when I use the second option)

2-Can I consider this new Worry scale as an interval variable and use OLS Regression rather than Ordinal Regression?

Thanks so much for the help,

Cüneyt